# Conflict of sent_http_* logging and proxy_hide_header in nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I am trying to log some variables set by application to nginx log. So certain HTTP response headers are set and then I log them successfully with $sent_http_* variables.

But then I don't want the info to be exposed to outside world so I tried to remove them by adding "proxy_hide_header". What happened is that it actually makes the variables empty so nothing is logged properly. Is there any work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can access responses from upstream module thru $upstream_* variables. For custom variables, $upstream_http_* can be used. Still you can use proxy_hide_header directive to remove any unwanted headers sent to end users.